# Modify data in text file using ASM 8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

Yo Guys , actually i want to do a Signup function using ASM 8086, so i use int 21h,40h to add my new data , but there has some issue there.

Due to i also do a login function (done ady), so at the end of the text file i will put a $ to tell the program this is the end line of the text file .

But after i add my new data in the text file the $ still at there , so the program cant define where is the end line

btw i only store Staff ID (STXXX) and password (5-digit only)in text file

format of text file :

(id)(password)(id2)(password2).............

---

Now Program :

*Before :*

**ST00112345$**

*After program :*

**ST00112345$ST00234567$**

---

What i want:

*Before :*

**ST00112345$**

*After program :*

**ST00112345ST00234567$**

---

Hope u guys can understand what i said and help me. Thanks and have a nice day !

At the below is my ASM file (2.asm) and text file (pw.txt)

```
.model
.stack
.data
    fileHandler2 dw ?
    pathName db "pw.txt",0
    buffer db 100 dup (?)

    nline db 0dh,0ah,"$"

    inputid label byte
    max db 6
    act db ?
    data1 db 6 dup("$")

    inputpw label byte
    max2 db 6
    act2 db ?
    data2 db 6 dup("$")

    saveData label byte
    max3 db 200
    act3 db ?
    sd db 200 dup("$")

    askid db "Enter new Staff ID: $"
    askpw db "Enter your Password: $"

    stepC db 0
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,3dh      ;function 3dh - open file
    mov al,2    ;010b   ;access mode - read/write
    lea dx,pathName     ;address of filename
    int 21h

    mov fileHandler2,ax ;save handler
    jc fexit        ;when error, cf=1

    mov ah,3fh      ;function 3fh - read file
    mov bx,fileHandler2 ;ready handler
    mov cx,100      ;read 100 bytes in file
    lea dx,buffer       ;ready buffer
    int 21h
    jc fexit    ;when error, cf=1

    mov bx,fileHandler2 ;ready handler
    jmp askla

fexit:
    jmp exit

askla:
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,askid
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah
    lea dx,inputid
    int 21h

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,nline
    int 21h

    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,askpw
    int 21h

    mov ah,0ah
    lea dx,inputpw
    int 21h

    mov si,0
    mov di,offset sd
    jmp rAddid
    
rAddid:
    mov si,0
    mov si,offset data1
    mov cx,5
    jmp Addid

Addid:
    mov bl,[si]
    mov [di],bl

    inc si
    inc di
    add stepC,1

    loop Addid
    jmp rAddpw

rAddpw:
    mov si,0
    mov si,offset data2
    mov cx,5
    jmp Addpw

Addpw:
    mov bl,[si]
    mov [di],bl

    inc si
    inc di
    add stepC,1

    loop Addpw

    mov bl,'$'
    mov [di],bl
    add stepC,1
    
    jmp rwFile

rwFile:
    mov si,0
    mov di,0
    
    mov si,offset sd
    mov ch,0

    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,fileHandler2
    mov cl,stepC
    lea dx,sd
    int 21h

    jmp cFile

cFile:
    mov ah,3eh      ;function 3eh - close file
    int 21h
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov ah,4ch      ;terminate
    int 21h

main endp
end main
```

---

```
ST00112345ST002P2345ST003AldenST00488988ST00587876$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:  INT 21h, FUNCTION 42h: Move File Pointer

to move the file position back one byte before writing, but only do it if the file already has the $, i.e. you're appending to an existing file of yours.

When you open a file for read/write, the file pointer is set to the beginning of the data currently in the file — though you read the whole file data, so the file pointer ends up at the end of the current data in the file.  Function 42h can move the file pointer relative to current file position, so with the right mode, -1 means back one byte.  <strike>(If you open a file for write/append instead, I believe the file pointer is initially positioned at the end of current file data.)</strike>

---

You can use the same 42h to test if the file is empty by moving the file pointer 0 bytes relative; its return value will tell if the file has 0 bytes or not — then you can conditionally move the file pointer back one byte so as to overwrite the old record's $ with your new data.

<strike>Alternatively, simply request to move the file pointer back one byte, and ignore errors it gives you (it should give an error when the file pointer is at 0 meaning the file is empty).</strike>

Comment: "(If you open a file for write/append instead, I believe the file pointer is initially positioned at the end of current file data.)" Don't think this is true in the DOS int 21h service land. "Alternatively, simply request to move the file pointer back one byte, and ignore errors it gives you (it should give an error when the file pointer is at 0 meaning the file is empty)." Fairly certain that DOS int 21h lets you seek to negative offsets, which will likely wrap around to very large positive ones (eg 4 GiB - 1 B, or for 64-bit seek 16 EiB - 1 B).

Comment: i see , but may i know the int 21h,42 will run after open the file or read file ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTmOFHOtFiXyOCp5si9AKXz5EjvsTgpigmvUjlbtq8tkknclciFwlu5wsZMuFPdUzgMTNk_w6wR92b9/pub

this is update code (although still cant run), may hlep me check it is correct ?

Comment: A file pointer is associated with an open file handle.

Comment: Ok, for 21h/42h, need to put 32-bit value in cx:dx.  You're putting 0, but needs to be -1 to back up one byte so as to overwrite the last $.